# How to insert data into datastore(mongodb)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am crawling through data, and I would like to insert these data into monogdb how to do?

1. this is crawling module. data were stored in 'docs'

```js
module.exports = {
    parseList(username,password) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        parseDKU.authenticateAndParse(username, password, 'https://webinfo.dankook.ac.kr/tiac/univ/lssn/ttmg/views/findTkcrsTmtblList.do?_view=ok&&sso=ok')
                .then( $ => {
                    if ($('#tmtblDscAplListTbl')) {
                        var docs = [];
                        const selector = '#tmtblDscAplListTbl td';
                        const td = $(selector); 
                        const tdLength = td.length/10;
                        for(let i =0; i < tdLength; i++){
                            var scoreInfo = {
                                stu_id: username,
                                course_code: ($(selector).eq(i * 10 + 1).text().trim()).concat('-'+$(selector).eq(i * 10 + 2).text().trim()),
                                course_name: $(selector).eq(i * 10 + 3).text().trim(),
                                prof_name: $(selector).eq(i * 10 + 6).text().trim()
                            }
                            docs.push(scoreInfo);
                            console.log(docs[i])
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log('fail to Login')
                    }
                    
                })
             })
    }
}
```

2. this is connection of mongodb, i want to 'docs'stored data insert into 'scorerelease' schema how to do this?

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var parseList = require('./parseList');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/testDB');


var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', function() {
    console.log('Connection Failed');
});

db.once('open', function() {
    console.log('Conneted!');
})

var scorerelease= mongoose.Schema({
    stu_id : 'String',
    course_code : 'String',
    course_name : 'String',
    // course_score : 'number',
    prof_name : 'String',

})
```

})

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose connection should be inside the app.js file and model Schemas should be in scoreRelease.js file

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

var scorerelease = mongoose.Schema({
  stu_id : 'String',
  course_code : 'String',
  course_name : 'String',
  // course_score : 'number',
  prof_name : 'String',

})

var ScoreRelease = mongoose.model('Book', scoreReleaseSchema);

module.exports = ScoreRelease;
```

Then you can store storerelese like this using async/await

```
   module.exports = {
  parseList(username, password) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      let result = await parseDKU.authenticateAndParse(
        username,
        password,
        "https://webinfo.dankook.ac.kr/tiac/univ/lssn/ttmg/views/findTkcrsTmtblList.do?_view=ok&&sso=ok"
      );

      if (result("#tmtblDscAplListTbl")) {
        var docs = [];
        const selector = "#tmtblDscAplListTbl td";
        const td = $(selector);
        const tdLength = td.length / 10;
        for (let i = 0; i < tdLength; i++) {
          await ScoreRelease({
            stu_id: username,
            course_code: $(selector)
              .eq(i * 10 + 1)
              .text()
              .trim()
              .concat(
                "-" +
                  $(selector)
                    .eq(i * 10 + 2)
                    .text()
                    .trim()
              ),
            course_name: $(selector)
              .eq(i * 10 + 3)
              .text()
              .trim(),
            prof_name: $(selector)
              .eq(i * 10 + 6)
              .text()
              .trim()
          }).save();
          docs.push(scoreInfo);
          console.log(docs[i]);
        }
      } else {
        console.log("fail to Login");
      }
    });
  }
};
```